# Magento Profiler only showing memory

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to use the inbuilt Magento (1.9) profiler to find some bottlenecks.
I've uncommented the line in the index.php and also enabled profiling under developer.
It's working as I'd expect in the admin area with large table of all the processes but on any page on the frontend it's just showing

```
[profiler]
Memory usage: real: 50855936, emalloc: 49801712
Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
```

And that's all, no other data.  I've cleared cache and all that good stuff.  I've viewed source and it's not in there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out.  Multi language site with each language in it's own subfolder.  I needed to uncomment

```
Varien_Profiler::enable();
```

In the index.php file in the subfolders